Cant' verify sign with go-schnorrkel
I'm trying sign raw message from polkadot.js.org and verifing it from golang code. I've tried the following:
signature, err := schnorrkel.NewSignatureFromHex(signatureHex)
transcript := schnorrkel.NewSigningContext([]byte("substrate"), []byte("my message"))
ok, err := key.Verify(signature, transcript)

polkadot.js verified it successfully, and verified the other sign, which is verified from golang code, successfully too. What am I doing wrong? How I can fix this?
